# Consuming 3rd party libraries in an ES6 library project

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I couldn`t figure out a way to import a library from both in a my own library module and then from the web application that uses both my library and the third party one.

I have been working on a browser side es6 library which uses some 3rd party libraries such as *lodash*.

Mylibrary.js

```
import _ from 'lodash';
```

MyApp.js

```
import MyClass from "js/MyLibrary"
import _ from "js/lodash"
```

As the paths to lodash are not some, mylibrary can not import lodash on browser.

as you can see it is not possible for me to know exact location of *lodash* while writing my library . In this example it is in "/js" folder.
So how should I import them in my library?

Comment: Is the user of your library going to use webpack or browsersify? Because in that case your library simply has `lodash` as npm dependency.

Comment: no , the user will not use webpack.